# Simplest way to convert a vue web app to an ios and android app

Tags: android, ios, vue.js

Back in 2013, I was on a project that used https://appcelerator.com/ to create a listing app for iOS. It worked great but we did still have a split between the website code and the app code.

Today I am tasked with creating an iOS and Android app from a vue website (PWA).

The requirement is simple.. to be able to receive native push notifications and to be able to "share to" the app.

The project is only in beta so there will likely be many more changes to the vue code base... the project is also from a startup where funds are not limitless.

I have had a look into nativescript but it doesn't seem like you can just wrap nativescript around a vue app and have a single code base.

I was wondering if it would be worth exploring this idea: **An app with a webview to local files of the vuejs app?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you're aiming for a hybrid app at this stage.
If you are using Vue 3 then check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-cordova which installs from the command line (vue-cli). The description there should give you a good start.

Comment: cordova! thank you

we're actually on vue2 at the moment due to the component lib being used, but i should imagine vue2 and cordova would play nicely

Comment: Yes, it will play with Vue2 all the same. If in doubt, just create an empty cordova project first and then add your existing code to src. Make sure vue exports not into the /build folder but /src_cordova (or wherever cordova is getting its content from)